# How to close modal window without jquery in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window in view:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div id="create_task_modal" className="modal fade" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              ... header ...
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              ... some elements ...
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addTask}>
                Save changes
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And function for add new category:

```
  addTask(e) {
    this.setState({
      taskTitle: e.target.value
    });

    // I want to close modal window here
  }
```

How can I close modal window in this function without jQuery?

Comment: Check out [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not nice variant, but I did it:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  className="btn btn-primary" 
  onClick={this.addTask} 
  data-dismiss="modal">
    Save changes
</button>
```